# NSURLConnection Uploading empty files

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlconnection

I am using **NSURLConnection** to submit a file and some information to a form using a HTTP Post. This form then uploads the file to an FTP server. 
This has worked for the past few weeks just fine. However at some point yesterday I must have changed something which causes it to upload empty files. So the files posted have the correct name and extension, but have no body data. 
Heres my code:

```
- (void)otherUploadingData: (NSString *)fileName {

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains
(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *filepath = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@/%@", documentsDirectory, fileName];
NSLog(@"File path for uploading method %@", filepath);

// Create data object from filepath
NSError *attributesError = nil;
NSDictionary *fileAttributes = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfItemAtPath:filepath error:&attributesError];
NSNumber *fileSizeNumber = [fileAttributes objectForKey:NSFileSize];
long long fileSize = [fileSizeNumber longLongValue];
NSLog(@"The size of the file is: %lld", fileSize); //Implemented this to check that my files were not of 0 size 

NSData* fileData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filepath];

//create request and set url, method
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://xx.xxx.xx"]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

//define charset for?

NSString *boundary = @"0xKhTmLbOuNdArY";
NSString *endBoundary = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary];

NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
[request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

NSMutableData *tempPostData = [NSMutableData data];
[tempPostData appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

// Sample Key Value for data
[tempPostData appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\"\r\n\r\n", @"username"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[tempPostData appendData:[@"xxx" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[tempPostData appendData:[endBoundary dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[tempPostData appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\"\r\n\r\n", @"password"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[tempPostData appendData:[@"xxx" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[tempPostData appendData:[endBoundary dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

// Sample file to send as data
[tempPostData appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"%@\"\r\n", fileName] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[tempPostData appendData:[@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[tempPostData appendData: fileData];
[tempPostData appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[request setHTTPBody:tempPostData];

// now lets make the connection to the web
NSError *returnError = nil;
NSHTTPURLResponse *returnResponse = nil;

NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&returnResponse error:&returnError];

NSString *htmlSTR = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData
                                          encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
//NSLog(@"The return string: %@" , htmlSTR);
SBJsonParser *jsonParser = [SBJsonParser new];
NSMutableDictionary *jsonResp = [jsonParser objectWithString:htmlSTR error:nil];
NSInteger success = [(NSNumber *) [jsonResp objectForKey:@"success"] integerValue];
NSLog(@"Json response : %@", jsonResp);

if (success == 1) {
    NSLog(@"File uploaded");
}
else {
    NSLog(@"Didnt upload");
}
```

}

Looking at the log of the application, I know that:

- Its taking the **correct** file
- The file has a **non-zero** size
- The 'File uploaded' log is triggered

Heres what I've tried:

- Manually selecting a file and sending that to the method (at the moment the file selector runs on a loop
- Reverting to a previous code

Does anybody have any ideas as to why it may be uploading a zero file? I've tried the code without the delete command and the same thing happens. The server details **are correct** and I do have access to the server.

Comment: Why don't you use Wireshark to check what is transmitted to the server?

Comment: And GIT to find out what you changed?

Comment: If the server correctly receives the file name then probably there is something wrong with the file content formatting. Also can you try to add Content-Length ? Another idea to try: add Content-Transfer-Encoding (and use either binary or base64 encoding)

Comment: @SergiySalyuk I've implemented this and I get a post length of 442 for my 57 Byte file. I dont think the file content is wrong because I havent touched the way it writes/zips files. Also when I download the files from organizer, they are as they should be.

Comment: @MartinR Ill have more server information within the hour. Wain, Ill have a look at that too. Thanks!